# Broadcom driver for Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04, broadcom

I have an issue with wifi on my Lenovo yoga 500 15 ibd laptop. It comes with Broadcom driver, for which i can't find any suitable driver. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.q LTS.
after command `lspci -nn -d 14e4:`

I get:

> 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:43ae] (rev 02)

Is there a driver for this card? Or is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Broadcom card is not yet supported; there is no Linux driver
for it at this time. This thread, also a Lenovo, solved the problem by replacing the card: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2296434
See page #3.

I suggest that you purchase a USB wifi device. I am sorry there isn't a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve written [an experimental ndiswrapper](https://bbs.belchi.org/foro/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=1124) driver with the same computer and the same chip.

is slow and work -40 dbm AL

The page is in Spanish but the driver works anyway!

is plug and quiet...

It is more stable than before